# Dynamic Initialize in c#

Tags: c#

I've a class

```
class sampleClass
{
    ...........
    ...........
    public sampleClass()
    {.........}
}
```

and in another class i created an array like

```
sampleClass[] X=new sampleClass[]{new sampleClass(),new sampleClass()}
```

here i gave 2 instance of the constructor. i need this dynamically..

that is the size of the array should be dynamically changed

Comment: Array sizes don't change dynamically in C#. You probably want a collection class, probably `List<T>`.

Comment: You've give the same comment to all three answers. That should suggest to you that your question didn't give enough details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
int size = // whatever

SampleClass[] array = new SampleClass[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    array[i] = new SampleClass();
}
```

EDIT: If you *really* want to avoid a for loop, you could do something like:

```
SampleClass[] array = Enumerable.Range(0, size) 
                                .Select(x => new SampleClass())
                                .ToArray();
```

... but I don't think that's actually better than using a loop.

Comment: @Pramodh: Why would you want to avoid a for loop? It's certainly *possible* using LINQ, but why would you want to?

Comment: @  Jon Skeet  : i'm expecting that . a linq approch

Comment: @Pramodh: Why would you expect a LINQ approach without asking for one, or mentioning LINQ anywhere in your question?

Comment: @ Jon Skeet: Thank you... LINQ is some more faster i think. And it is less in code.

Comment: Why you think LINQ is faster in this scenario ? Did you measure it ? I would expect that simpler is faster and here for loop is simpler. You could write for loop yourself probably. LINQ is not always better.

Comment: @ThorinOakenshield LINQ certainly isn't faster in most cases. Internally there will still be a for loop or some kind of stacked iterators and possibly one or more intermediate arrays before the final length is really known. I'd expect a LINQ solution to at most have the same performance as a well-written for loop until measurement proves me wrong. (In that case I'd probably revise my code.) The only undeniable advantage is the compact code you have to write *yourself*.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a syntactic sugar, you can gain the same using your own code:

```
sampleClass[] X = new sampleClass[num];
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
   X[i] = new sampleClass();
}
```

Comment: @Pramodh, how would you like it look? If it's dynamic you know "num" only at runtime, so I don't understand exactly what is the mechanism you're looking for.

Comment: The num value is dynamic. in one case i gave num=4.

and in anothe case i give num=10. so in each case i have to iterate. Only the "num" is dynamic.but the value in the array will be always the constructor

Comment: @Pramodh, I think it's not possible. The code that actually runs in your original example is similar, the compiler generates code that performs it (you can take a look using reflector). There's no "ready to go" functionality in the IL that supports initialize an array with default instances. All can be done is just to get nicer looking code (Like the updated code in Jon Skeet answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the array using a loop:

```
sampleClass[] X = new sampleClass[123];
for (int i = 0; i < X.Length; ++i)
  X[i] = new sampleClass();
```

If your class was a value type the array is initialized when it is allocated:

```
struct sampleStruct { ... }

sampleStruct[] X = new sampleStruct[123];
// No need to initialize every array cell.
```

However, using a struct instead of a class is not something you should do simply to avoid a loop. You can read more about [value types on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34yytbws(VS.71).aspx).